# Search tamil fonts in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, search, utf-8, tamil

How do you use search a MySQL database with Tamil fonts and retrieve and display the data using PHP?

Comment: Have to be more specific, please.

Comment: Neither PHP nor MySQL have a GUI, and neither of them uses fonts. Your question then does not make sense. Are you asking about character sets instead?

Answer (score 1):

Tamil characters are part of the [Unicode spec](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/tamil.html) and have been supported for years. Have you tried making a php page which takes Tamil input and stores it into the database?

If it didn't work, post your code.

Comment: I am in search of the code.If you have some example code pls post here.I will try whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the unicode character setup (utf8) to support multiple languages in mysql. Take a look at the example below.

[Multiple Language Support - Mysql](http://www.discussweb.com/database-support/1557-mysql-supports-indian-language-character-sets.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UTF-8 as the encoding for your MySQL DB. This allows you to later retrieve and store data to the MySQL database as you usually would.

For UTF8 Tamil input, I'd suggest you the following resources

- Google Transliterate: http://www.google.com/transliterate/tamil
- NHM Writer
- E-kalappai

Answer (score 0):

Rekha, are your MySQL database and your PHP file encoded in UTF8?

If so, just query the DB with a string that contains Tamil characters the same way you would with any other string.